# why my solution to $\frac{\partial tr(ABA^{T})}{\partial A}$ is wrong?

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative

Given $A$ and $B$ are matrix，I know the true answer of the derivative $\frac{\partial tr(ABA^{T})}{\partial A}=A(B+B^{T})$
However, I don't know why my solution is wrong?
Here is my solution:
" First we have, $\frac{\partial tr(ABA^{T})}{\partial A}=\frac{\partial tr(A^{T}AB)}{\partial A}$. 
According to chain rule, $\frac{\partial tr(A^{T}AB)}{\partial A}=\frac{\partial tr(A^{T}AB)}{\partial (A^{T}A)}\cdot \frac{\partial A^{T}A}{\partial A}$ 
As $\frac{\partial tr(AB)}{\partial A}=B^{T}$, hence $\frac{\partial tr(A^{T}AB)}{\partial (A^{T}A)}=B^{T}$
And I know $\frac{\partial A^{T}A}{\partial A}$ is a supermatrix.
So, the results must not be $A(B+B^{T})$ "
Could anyone tell me which steps are wrong?

Comment: "According to chain rule"... what is the chain rule for matrix calculus?

Comment: Can you explain what a supermatrix is and why it implies that the result cannot be $A(B+B^T)$?

Comment: I think i know what's wrong. In the wikipedia page of Matrix calculus, there is a sentence, "Note that exact equivalents of the scalar product rule and chain rule do not exist when applied to matrix-valued functions of matrices", so there is no chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write the expression in terms of the Frobenius Product for simplicity:

$$\text{Tr}(ABA^T) = AB:A$$

Then, we have:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
d\text{Tr}(ABA^T) & = d(AB):A + AB:dA \\
& = ((dA)B + A(dB)):A + AB:dA \\
& = (dA)B:A + AB:dA \\
& = A:(dA)B + AB:dA \\
& = AB^T:(dA) + AB:dA \\
& = (AB^T + AB):dA \\
& = A(B^T + B):dA \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Finally, we get:

$$ \frac{\partial \text{Tr}(ABA^T)}{\partial A} = A(B + B^T)$$

---

In above, I used the following properties:

$$ A:BC = B^TA:C = AC^T:B$$

and

$$(A + B):C = A:C + B:C$$

Answer (score 0):

One good way to find derivatives of scalar functions of matrices is by use of first order approximation. Let $f(X) = Tr(XBX^\top)$ be our function. Let $Z = X+\Delta X$. Then,
$$f(Z) \approx f(X)+<\Delta X,\nabla f(X)>$$ 
where $<X,Y> = Tr(X^\top Y) = Tr(Y^\top X)$. 
Now, let's calculate $f(Z)$ directly.
$$f(Z) = Tr((X+\Delta X)B(X+\Delta X)^\top)=Tr(XBX^\top)+Tr(XB\Delta X^\top)+Tr(\Delta XBX^\top)+Tr(\Delta XB\Delta X^\top).$$
Last term is quadratic in $\Delta X$ and can be ignored for our first order approximation. Hence, 
$$f(Z) \approx f(X) + Tr(\Delta X^\top X(B+B^\top)) = f(X)+<\Delta X,X(B+B^\top)>.$$
Comparing with the definition of first-order approximation above we conclude $\nabla f(X) = X(B+B^\top)$.